# How to remove() a file in the kernel space?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

How to remove() a file in the kernel space ?
In the user space we can simply call the function remove() from the stdio.h library.
But in module programming no such facility is present.
The LED on my ethernet port is denoted by a file in the /tmp region named GPIO_22_LED when the LED is ON.If the file is non existent then the webpage query will take the status as not connected and vice versa.I am already using the proc/ entries but in my present circumstances it is not feasible as this is a different mode of my device in which the proc entries are rendered useless due to another feature kicking in.

Comment: You should explain why you want to remove file in kernel; it is a bad idea and you should avoid doing that.... Do that housekeeping in a helper user program (perhaps related to `udev`)

Comment: The file is a signalling file ,After my process completion i would wish that the file be deleted.The presence of the file is itself the signal so the converse will also be important. @Basile Starynkevitch

Comment: This is not a good reason. I don't understand what signaling means to you here. You might have e.g. several devices, one for controlling and signaling purposes, another for the data I/O. Also, learn about `udev`; perhaps provide pseudo files in `/proc` or `/sys`; and your question is still too broad. Explain much more what and *why* you want to do that (by editing the question). What exact kind of kernel module, what driver (for what hardware) are you designing? There are probably better ways to do all that!!!

Comment: Practically speaking, you **cannot remove** files **in a kernel driver**. Consider making a user-space web application (perhaps a CGI) which queries the driver.

Comment: Then i plan to create a new proc entry besides my previous one which is pertinent to the current mode only.What do you say ? @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: Did you study how other ethernet drivers are made in the kernel?

Comment: Due to the trivial nature of the task at hand and the project deadline i hav'nt had the opportunity to peek into the ethernet drivers lately.I have only tweaked and modified the gpio modules according to my fancies Sir.

Comment: You won't meet deadlines if you don't code according to *existing kernel practices*. http://kernelnewbies.org/ ; please cooperate with other kernel developers!

Comment: Thanks for the site.I will try to cooperate with other developers.Right now i have to deliver my task tomorrow so i will have to get with the proc entry way.Thanks for the interest and the advice though.

Comment: You won't deliver for tomorrow (and if you did, it will be crappy code). Kernel development needs months of learning and practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my discussion with an advanced kernel developer ,I came to learn that it is not possible to delete files in a kernel module.So as per my requirement i have modified my signalling mechanism so that it now includes remaking proc entries in the system.Thanks @Basile

Comment: Although you've made the right decision, you are somewhat mischaracterizing the facts; it is *possible* but it is strongly *discouraged*, breaks all sorts of design principles, and must be done by quite roundabout means.